# Describe the integral solutions to this cubic equation.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the following cubic equation in $c$:

$c^3 - 3c^2(a+b) + 3c(a+b) -3ab(a+b)-3=0$

Does this equation have infinitely many integer solutions $(a,b,c)$ ?

EDIT: My attempt was rerwriting it as a linear in $a+b$, such that $a+b=\dfrac{c^3 -3}{3c^2 +3ab- 3c}$

Which shows that $a+b$ is an integral solution whenever $3c^2 + 3ab -3c$ divides $c^3 -3$. The question now would be on the existence of infinitely many integers $(a, b, c)$ such that the divisibility holds ?

Comment: Can those who are downvoting this  question explain why they are doing so  ? Because i have seen so many posts on SE with the same style.

Comment: I agree there are some rogue downvoters doing the rounds here, not only for this question but for many others as well. Although perhaps the downvote in this case might be because you did not show what you have tried, your attempt,  your line of thought, etc.

Comment: @Isaac. I assume it is because you haven't shown any of your own work. It is more out less random whether that actually leads to downvotes on any given post, but technically we are supposed to discourage such questions.

Comment: @User, it's now edited.

Comment: @Arthur, okay i have now shown my attempt in the edit.

Comment: Probably [the only solutions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6tKib.png) for $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @Lucian, please may you kindly explain how you got obtained those values ?

Comment: @Isaac.: Most probably a computer search within a bound.

Comment: @Lucian No, there are others, for example, $(-359,610,-381)$ and $(127,283,1257)$. (Found with a computer search.)

Comment: @Théophile: I searched for $|a|,~|b|,~|c|\le100.$ Then, when I saw that $c=-3$ seems to be the only value, I extended the search to $|a|,~|b|\le10^3.$